# Trying to backtrace an uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason ... may only be called on RLMArray

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having trouble tracking down the source of one of these errors:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'This method may only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an RLMRealm'

I know that it is most likely I am calling a `filter()` or a `sorted()` function on an `Object` instance that has not been stored in a realm properly.  To make things worse, my app works perfectly okay when run in the simulator, but it doesn't when I run it on my iPhone, so thread timing is probably at play.

As I am using Swift, it is hard to trap and backtrace the Exception.  Are there any tricks you can suggest other than stepping through every step until I find where it is happening?

Comment: `so thread timing is probably at play` you're using Realm so that is unlikely; you should find a place where you manually instantiate a `RLMArray` and then call `filter` or `sorted` on it.

Comment: can you show screenshot of code with error! @pbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem, but it is interesting how it ends up being reported.

The cause of the fault is that part of my code was attempting to add a notification block to a List<> within an Object that was in the process of being committed to its realm.  To overcome this fault, I make sure the commit happens first, then the notification block is added second: life is good again.  It is interesting that it only shows up when run on an actual device and not in the simulator, but such are the vagaries of simulators.

Perhaps it would be helpful for realm.io to look at a precondition for `addNotificationBlock` regarding this fault and throw a more meaningful error that makes it easier for programmers to trap and resolve.

Comment: p.s.  I did not find any tricks to isolating the fault quickly.  I went through everything step by step: it takes time.

Comment: You can use an [exception breakpoint](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) to have Xcode break into the debugger at the point where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the breakpoint tip, but for this bug, the exception is thrown deep within the Realm framework after my code has returned, so I didn't find the error using this technique.

Comment: From the exception breakpoint, you can see what exception is being thrown and why. You can then walk up the backtrace to find a frame that's in your own code, to see which line of your code is triggering the exception. You can then start to reason about why your code might be triggering that specific exception.

Comment: I did try that, but my code had completed before the error was raised, so none of my code was in the stack. I found it by placing breakpoints in my code until I isolated the line before the crash: from that I reasoned the fault. It's all good now